# Produce \' in a string replacement

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, quote, escape

As you know, functions such as `replace-regexp-in-string` and `replace-match` have an argument LITERAL, meaning ...

```
If optional ... arg LITERAL is non-nil, insert NEWTEXT literally.
Otherwise treat ‘\’ as special ...
```

My intent is to replace all occurrences of a single-quote with a back-slash followed by a single-quote. However, the output does not evaluate that way:

```
 (replace-regexp-in-string "'" "\'" "a'b'c" nil t)
```

"a'b'c"

```
 (replace-regexp-in-string "'" "\\'" "a'b'c" nil t)
```

"a\\'b\\'c"

The result I need, by hook or by crook, is:

"a\'b\'c"

Comment: @npostavs How is that a helpful comment? Anyway, no, I'm not confused, but I do need to generate the text string as I specified.

Comment: Backslash will be escaped in displayed strings. Try inserting the return value of this function to see that it does what you want it to.

Comment: @user1404316 okay, let me rephrase it then. I'm confused by your question as to whether you want a string composed of `a` backslash apostrophe etc, or if you want the string represented by the Lisp string literal `"a\'b\'c"`

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 You're quite right! If you post your comment as answer, I can accept it and mark the question closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elisp displays strings in a `read`able format, where characters have to be escaped, and in this case it displays `\` as `\\`, because it has to be escaped.

Try `insert`ing the return value like this to see that it's doing what you want it to:

```
(insert (replace-regexp-in-string "'" "\\'" "a'b'c" nil t))
```